# Add a command for bash script to terminal

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, command

I have `studio.sh` file in my `android-studio/bin folder`, which I would like to use as a command in bash (like launching any other normal application).

I read somewhere that adding this line to `~/.profile` should work,

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/goel/android-studio/bin
```

But it doesn't work. Whats the correct process?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: I would avoid having a very long `$PATH`. Can't you decide to put all your executables (both programs & scripts - perhaps as symlinks) into `$HOME/bin/`  and add only that directory to your `PATH` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your PATH in a .profile, you still have to make the shell **read** the .profile. Starting a new terminal is sometimes not enough (some terminals don't read the .profile), in which case you have to log out and back in.

Answer (score 2):

Add the script folder name to PATH environment variable in `~/bash.rc` file
and you can also create alias for you script in `~/bash.rc`
and source the `/etc/bash.bashrc` file, now you can issue your script or alias name in any terminal. Hope this helps.

Comment: `~/bashrc` is the commonly used file and don't forget to `source ~/.bashrc` after each modification.

Answer (score 0):

Is `studio.sh` executable? Have you tried `./studio.sh` inside its containing folder to check whether it runs at all?